# Make steps in the incremental values with a button

Tags: javascript, html, button, increment

I made this code that increments a number with a button. I would like to add a condition when the number reaches a defined value, in order to display a text. Thanks for the help.

My code:

```js
const incrementCount = document.getElementById("btn");
const totalCount = document.getElementById("compteur");


var count = 0;


totalCount.innerHTML = count;

const handleIncrement = () => {
  count++;
  totalCount.innerHTML = count;

};

incrementCount.addEventListener("click", handleIncrement);
```

```html
<div id="compteur"></div>
<div id="btn" ontouchstart ontouchend></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have a `maxCount` variable and compare the new count to the max after each iteration. Once the max is reached, a message will display.

In the example below, the count will keep going. The `alert` is wrapped in a `setTimeout` so that the count can be updated to `10`, before the alert dialog is displayed.

```js
const
  incrCountBtn = document.querySelector('#btn'),
  totalCountEl = document.querySelector('#compteur'),
  maxCount = 10,
  message = 'You have reached the limit';

let count = 0;

totalCountEl.innerText = count;

const handleIncrement = () => {
  count += 1;
  totalCountEl.innerText = count;

  if (count === maxCount) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      alert(message);
    }, 100);
  }
};

incrCountBtn.addEventListener('click', handleIncrement);
```

```html
<div id="compteur"></div>
<button type="button" id="btn" ontouchstart ontouchend>Increment</button>
```